# How to read the table from .iqy file

Tags: r

How to read connection from ".iqy" file. I'm using

```
     con <- file("ABC1.iqy", "r", blocking = FALSE)
     readLines(con=con,n=-1L,ok=TRUE, warn=FALSE,encoding='unknown').
```

There is a table with multiple columns which i need to get from the above web query link.

When I run the code I get the output as:

- [1] "WEB"
  [2] "1"
  [3] "https:abc.../excel/execution/EPnx?view=vrs"
  [4] ""
  [5] ""
  [6] "Selection=AllTables"
  [7] "Formatting=None"
  [8] "PreFormattedTextToColumns=True"
  [9] "ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True"
  [10] "SingleBlockTextImport=False"
  [11] "DisableDateRecognition=False"
  [12] "DisableRedirections=False"
  [13] ""

I'm not sure how to get the complete data frame with column and rows.

Comment: try replace "ABC1.iqy" with the url from line 3 of the result. I don't know .iqy file  abut they appear to be a specification of the query source and some attributes to apply to the results

Comment: @epi99 I tried it, it gives the below output: description 
"https:abc.../excel/execution/EPnx?view=vrs" " 
  class 
"url-wininet" 
mode 
 "r" 
text 
 "text" 
 opened 
 "opened" 
can read 
"yes" 
 can write 
 "no"

Comment: Thank you  for the help guys. I got the data frame as told by @epi99. I read the link directly.